# Asymptotic time complexity exponential function

Tags: algorithm

Dear friends here I am getting some confusion regarding time complexity of my algorithm. My algorithm has time complexity `3^(.5n)`. Is it correct way to write `3^(.5n)` as `(3^.5)^n`. In one thesis I got it.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it's about math formula

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is correct way. It is known [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties) for exponentiation

`(a^b)^c = a^(b*c)`

But what is relation of math formula to programming?

Comment: Probably you doubt due to confusing with a^b^c - that is another story...